# How to specify static ID for "available" and "selected" panel of item-selector?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

i need to know, How to specify static ID for "available" and "selected" panel of itemselector?
The reason is, based on "available" item selected value, i need to restore "selected" panel value(But not the selected value to be display, entire new storevalue). Please provide your ideas???

Comment: Waiting for month to get the answer..... :(

Comment: It get overed another month..... but still no update.